# Pathlib issue: iteration over pathlist ist skipped -> Why?

Tags: python, python-3.7, pathlib

I would be happy to learn why the for loop is not being executed? Event though a list of WindowsPaths gets printed. Thank you very much in advance.

```
from pathlib import Path

pathlist = Path("test_data").glob('**/*some_file*.json')
print(list(pathlist))

for path in pathlist:
    print("This never gets printed.")
```

Comment: Because `pathlist` might be empty.

Comment: `pathlist` is a generator. You consumed it all when you called `list(pathlist)`, so there's nothing left.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much! Sometimes the solution is so simple you don't think of it :)